# Append a new line to csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, append, writer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zon5M.png)I have a csv file and I want to append new lines to it when I used the code, the list didn't append to a new line, it appended the list to the last line of the csv file `

```
List1=["test2"] 
List2=["test1"]
with open (folder + '\\' + 'test.csv', 'a+', newline = '') as f_object:
    writer_object = writer(f_object)
    writer_object.writerow(List1)
    writer_object.writerow(List2)
```

this is the output of the code

[output of the python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zon5M.png)

Comment: Try removing the `newline = ''` from the `open()`

Comment: it didn't work, it has the same output

Comment: That would mean that your original csv file did not have proper end of line at the end of the file. I would suggest adding it manually, if its one off file, else you can write a newline to the file before you call `writerow`

Comment: I couldn't change it manually as the script will be run using Jenkins, how could I write a newline to the file before calling writerow?

Comment: You can add `f_object.write('\n')` before `writer_object = writer(f_object)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List1=["test2"] 
List2=["test1"]
with open (r"Z:\Images\Test\test.csv", 'a+') as f_object:
    writer_object = csv.writer(f_object)
    writer_object.writerow(List1)
    writer_object.writerow(List2)
```

Comment: it didn't work as well the output still the same